# SCSS not working IONIC2/3 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a simple Ionic2/3 example using the Tabs template in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dxunmr?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts).
I'm trying the change the size of **P** & color, yet it's not working (No error message).

#### home.scss

```
page-home{
  p {
    font-size: 100px !important;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

#### home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <p>TEST SHOULD BE 50PX</p>  <!-- there is no change here -->
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For separate SCSS you have to use selector.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss']
})
```

**SCSS**

Selector from @Component and Parent class of SCSS file must be same.

```
.page-home {
  p {
    font-size: 100px !important;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**GLOBAL SCSS**

You can use SCSS from **APP.SCSS** file. No selector is required for this.

Comment: It's not working, I think there is an issue with StackBlitz

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the style in your component. This is what your component definition should look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss']
})
```

Also, your CSS selector is wrong. I don't know what `page-home` is supposed to do. I recommend assigning a class to the `ion-content` element.

**SCSS:**

```
.page-content {
  p {
    font-size: 100px !important;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="page-content" padding>
    <p>TEST SHOULD BE 50PX</p>  <!-- there is no change here -->
</ion-content>
```

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kjmeut).